# Accessing an object from another class C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop, object, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a Library system. I have a source file called 3.cpp, several classes called Game.h, DVD.h, Book.h, Library.h and Media.h.

i am creating an object called lib in 3.cpp and I am trying to access the lib object from the Game class. How can I do this? I am using Eclipse onMac os.

The 3.cpp source file is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Library.h" // include header of Library class
#include "Game.h" // include header of Game class
#include "DVD.h" // include header of DVD class
#include "Book.h" // include header of Book class
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Library lib;

    while( 1 ){

        char mainSelect;
        char gameOption, name[30], platform[30], copies[10];
        char dvdOption, director[30];
        char bookOption, author[30];
        char mainMenu;

        // Read user selection
        cin.getline( name, 80);
        mainSelect = name[0];

        // Switch statement to select between the options
        switch (mainSelect){
           case '1':
              break;
           case '2':
               break;
           case '3':
               break;
           case '4':
               exit(0);
               break;
           case '5':
               cout << "Invalid selection!" << endl;
               system("pause");
               break;
        }

        if (mainSelect == '1'){

           cin.getline( name, 80);
           dvdOption = name[0];

        switch (dvdOption){

           case '1':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD: ";
              cin.getline( name, 80);
              cout << "Enter Director of DVD: ";
              cin.getline(director, 80);
              cout << "Enter no of copies: ";
              cin.getline(copies, 80);
              lib.insertDVD( name, director, atoi(copies));
              break;
           case '2':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD:\n";
              cin.getline(name, 80);
              lib.deleteDVD(name);
              break;
           case '3':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD:\n";
              cin.getline(name, 80);
              DVD *item;
              item = lib.searchDVD( name );
              if( item != NULL){
                cout << "DVD found\n" << item->name << endl << item->director << endl << item->copies << endl;
              }
              else
              cout << "DVD not found\n";
              break;
           case '4':
              break;
           case '5':
              exit(0);
              break;
           case '6':
              cout << "Invalid selection!" << endl;
              system("pause");
              break;
        }
        }

        else if (mainSelect == '2'){
          "I need to add a method here to call the GameMenu method from the Game class."


    return 0;
}
```

The Game class code is:

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include "Media.h"
#include "Library.h"
using namespace std;

class Game : public Media{
public:

    char platform[45];
    char gameOption, name[30], platform[30], copies[10];

    void GameMenu(){
cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
           cout << "*******************  Game Menu  ********************" << endl;
           cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "* PROGRAM          DESCRIPTION                     *" << endl;
           cout << "* ------------------------------------------------ *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*   1              Add a new Game                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*   2              Delete a Game                   *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*   3              Search for a Game               *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*   4              Return to the previous Menu     *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "*   5              EXIT                            *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "* ------------------------------------------------ *" << endl;
           cout << "*                                                  *" << endl;
           cout << "****************************************************" << endl;

            cin.getline( name, 80);
            gameOption = name[0];

        switch (gameOption){

           case '1':
             cout << "Enter Name of Game: ";
             cin.getline( name, 80);
             cout << "Enter game platform: ";
             cin.getline(platform, 80);
             cout << "Enter no of copies: ";
             cin.getline(copies, 80);
             lib.insertGame( name, platform, atoi(copies));
             break;
           case '2':
             cout << "Enter Name of Game:\n";
             cin.getline(name, 80);
             lib.deleteGame(name);
             break;
           case '3':
             cout << "Enter Name of Game:\n";
             cin.getline(name, 80);
             Game *item;
             item = lib.searchGame( name );
             if( item != NULL){
             cout << "Game found\n" << item->name << endl << item->platform << endl << item->copies << endl;
             }
             else
             cout << "Game not found\n";
             break;
             case '4':
             exit(0);
             break;
           case '5':
             cout << "Invalid selection!" << endl;
             system("pause");
             break;
        }
    }

};


#endif // end of "#ifndef" block
```

I am also getting some errors as I try to access the lib object created in the Game class. The errors I get are:

```
1. Use of undefined identifier lib.
2. Method insertGame could not be resolved.
3. Method deleteGame could not be resolved.
```

Comment: There's too much code here, please isolate your problem in a minimal example (less than 10 or 20 lines of code). There are too many classes and files here and it's hard to figure out what your problem is...

Answer (score 3):

## The problems:

You have defined `Library lib;` as local variable of `main()`.  This means that you can access to this variable in main() but nowhere else.

Unfortunately,  you refer to `lib` in the member function `GameMenu()` belonging to the `Game` class.  `GameMenu() does not see the local variables of the calling functions.

I try to make it simple: the `GameMenu()`function lives in the black box of its class.  It can use its own local variables, such as `item`, as well as the class members, such as `gameOption`.  But not the variables of the world outise the black box.

The other errors are only consequences of the first. For example, in your statement `lib.insertGame(name, platform, atoi(copies));`, as the compiler doesn't know what `lib` is, he complains, because he doesn't know what he can do with an object that it doesn't know.

There is also another problem with `collection[numGames].copies` that you have defined as a c-string in the class, but try to manage like an `int`.

You have also a structural issue.  It's not an error, but it's a bad habit.
If you put a class in a header, you should put only its declaractions (data members and function declarations) and not the function definitions.

## Solution

First simplify the **`Game.h` header** as follows:

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include "Media.h"
using namespace std;

class Library;  // forward declaration, will dbe detailed later 
class Game : public Media{  // no code 
public:
    char platform[45];
    char gameOption, name[30];   
    int copies;    // change to numeric 

    void GameMenu(Library& lib);  // pass an argument called lib by reference
};
#endif // end of "#ifndef" block
```

Then put the code in a **new `Game.cpp` file**:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Library.h"

void Game::GameMenu(Library& lib)  // now he knows lib. 
{
    ...  // put your code here
    cin>>copies;   //  instead of getline() 
    lib.insertGame(name, platform, copies);  // no atoi() anymore, its already an int 
    ...
}
```

Now think about the overall structure of your code:  for the moment, there is a menu in `3.cpp` and a menu in `Game`.  It's logic in `Library`, because these menu functions are really about managing a library object.  It makes less sense in `Game`, but up to you to choose.

Finally,  if you're learning c++,  I strongly advise you to get rid of your `c[]` strings, `strcpy()`, `strcmp()` and alike , and opt for c++ `string`

Comment: Why am I creating another .cpp file. And do I do this for everything such as DVD, Books??

Comment: How can I put the menus for game, dvd, and books in the library??

Comment: Because it's a good pracice to put implementation of member functions in a cpp, and definition of the class only in the header.  Another reason is that your class definition doesn't rely on full Library definition, whereas the member's definition does.  Hence, if you would keep everything in a single header, you'd need to includ eLibrary, which needs to include your header, which needs....  You'd have a circular dependency that will prevent compilation.